# Python: Binary Tree Class: Reconstruct with traversals

Tags: python, class, tree, binary-tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to make a function that uses my ListBinaryTree: class to constructs and prints a binary tree based on the inorder and preorder traversals given as input prompts (in string form, eg. Inorder = 213, Preorder = 123). My Binary Tree class is as follows:

```
class ListBinaryTree:
"""A binary tree class with nodes as lists."""
DATA = 0    # just some constants for readability
LEFT = 1
RIGHT = 2   

def __init__(self, root_value, left=None, right=None):
    """Create a binary tree with a given root value
    left, right the left, right subtrees        
    """ 
    self.node = [root_value, left, right]

def create_tree(self, a_list):
    return ListBinaryTree(a_list[0], a_list[1], a_list[2])

def insert_value_left(self, value):
    """Inserts value to the left of this node.
    Pushes any existing left subtree down as the left child of the new node.
    """
    self.node[self.LEFT] = ListBinaryTree(value, self.node[self.LEFT], None)

def insert_value_right(self, value):
    """Inserts value to the right of this node.
    Pushes any existing left subtree down as the left child of the new node.
    """      
    self.node[self.RIGHT] = ListBinaryTree(value, None, self.node[self.RIGHT])

def insert_tree_left(self, tree):
    """Inserts new left subtree of current node"""
    self.node[self.LEFT] = tree

def insert_tree_right(self, tree):
    """Inserts new left subtree of current node"""
    self.node[self.RIGHT] = tree

def set_value(self, new_value):
    """Sets the value of the node."""
    self.node[self.DATA] = new_value

def get_value(self):
    """Gets the value of the node."""
    return self.node[self.DATA]

def get_left_subtree(self):
    """Gets the left subtree of the node."""
    return self.node[self.LEFT]

def get_right_subtree(self):
    """Gets the right subtree of the node."""
    return self.node[self.RIGHT]

def __str__(self):
    return '['+str(self.node[self.DATA])+', '+str(self.node[self.LEFT])+', '+\
 str(self.node[self.RIGHT])+']'
```

So far I have the following:

```
def reconstruct():
    inorder = input("Please enter the inorder sequence:")
    preorder = input("Please enter the preorder sequence:")
    #root = preorder[0]
    #left_bottom = inorder[0]
    #right_bottom = inorder[len(inorder)-1]
    my_tree = ListBinaryTree(int(preorder[0]))
    my_tree.insert_tree_left(int(inorder[0]))
    my_tree.insert_tree_right(int(inorder[len(inorder)-1]))
    print (my_tree)
```

But it only works for a tree with 1 or 2 levels: 
An example of the output would be:

Call the  function

```
reconstruct()
```

Prompt:

```
Please enter the inorder sequence:213
Please enter the preorder sequence:123
```

Print result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

How do I change my function so that it can construct a tree with theoretically infinite amount of traversals/ higher levels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the posted code does not work as you show: the class has no constructor arguments.  Most of all, you need to consult your class materials to see how to reconstruct the tree from the two given orders.

- The head of inorder is the root of the tree.
- Find this element in the preorder.
- Split the preorder at this point: elements before the root
  are in its left subtree; elements after are in the right subtree.
- Use these to split the inorder similarly.
- Recur on each of the left and right subtrees.

Does that get you going?

---

Let's see about that pseudo-code:

```
def build_tree(inorder, preorder):
    if len(inorder) == 1:
        make a one-node tree of this node
        return this tree
    head = inorder[0]
    head_pos = position of head in preorder[]
    left_pre = preorder[:head_pos]
    right_pre = preorder[head_pos+1:]
    left_in = inorder[1:-len(right_pre)]
    right_in = inorder[-len(right_pre):]
    left_tree = build_tree(left_in, left_pre)
    right_tree = build_tree(right_in, right_pre)
    make a tree that has
        head as its root
        left_tree as its left subtree
        right_tree as its right subtree
    return this tree
```

Comment: The reconstruct() is just a seperate function that calls on the ListBinaryTree class. It works for me. You just have to call the function with: reconstruct() and it prompts for the traversals. I don't understand how you would implement recursion for this though. It confuses me

Comment: Is there an individual aspect of recursion with which you have trouble, or is that a general problem with the concept of recursion?  If it's a general problem, then I suggest that you look up a tutorial on recursion or find a friend who understands; explaining the whole idea over text is beyond the scope of StackOverflow.  If it's just a specific problem, then please ask a follow-up question, as this is critical to the assignment.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  That might be the difference.

Comment: Is it possible for you to give me some pseudo code on how the recursive call should look?